# Handling errors within loops through exceptions

Tags: error-handling

Tried my first python program to read temp sensor and output to influxdb

Occasionally temp sensor gives error "IndexError: list index out of range" and loop ends

I want loop to wait 15 seconds on this error and then continue the loop (sensor usually corrects itself by then on the next read)

**My code:**

```
import os                                                  
import glob                                                
import time
import urllib
import urllib2
import httplib
import json

from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
client = InfluxDBClient(host='192.168.1.7', port=8086)
#client.get_list_database()
client.switch_database('influxdb1')
                                                
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')                              
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

base_dir = '/sys/devices/w1_bus_master1/'                  
device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')[0]            

while True:

    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'                  
    def read_temp_raw():
       f = open(device_file, 'r')
       lines = f.readlines()                                  
       f.close()
       return lines

    def read_temp():
       lines = read_temp_raw()
       while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':                   
          time.sleep(0.2)
          lines = read_temp_raw()
       equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')                        
       if equals_pos != -1:
          temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
          temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0                 
          return temp_c

    temp = float(read_temp())


    json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": "YOUR_MEASUREMENT",
            "tags": {
                 "Device": "YOUR_DEVICE",
                 "ID": "YOUR_ID"
            },
            "fields": {
                 "outside_temp": temp,
            }
        }
    ]
    client.write_points(json_body)

    time.sleep(60)
******************************************************

which works ok :)

When I edit the code to catch the exception.....

******************************************************

while True:

    except IndexError:
        time.sleep(15)
        continue

    device_file = device_folder + '/w1_slave'                  # store the details
    def read_temp_raw():
       f = open(device_file, 'r')
       lines = f.readlines()                                   # read the device details
       f.close()
       return lines

    def read_temp():
       lines = read_temp_raw()
       while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':                   
          time.sleep(0.2)
          lines = read_temp_raw()
       equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')                        
       if equals_pos != -1:
          temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
          temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0                 
          return temp_c

    temp = float(read_temp())


    json_body = [
        {
            "measurement": "YOUR_MEASUREMENT",
            "tags": {
                 "Device": "YOUR_DEVICE",
                 "ID": "YOUR_ID"
            },
            "fields": {
                 "outside_temp": temp,
            }
        }
    ]
    client.write_points(json_body)

    time.sleep(60)

************************************************************

I get following error...

  File "temptoinfluxdb2.py", line 22
    except IndexError:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Where am i going wrong please?
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always need to use the `except` block in combination with a `try` block.

So the code in the `try` block is executed until an exception (in that case IndexError) occurs.

```
try:
# Execution block
except IndexError:
# Error handling
```

You could also use a more general approach with `except Exception as e`, which catches not just the IndexError but any exception.

Check the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) for further information.